# Container App wont run but docker run works fine

Tags: docker, azure-container-apps

I am confused and couldn't find much info on this issue. I have a docker image based on ubuntu 20.4 image and runs a bunch of scripts. Using docker run locally works and the container function as it should, but Once I deploy the image to container app, I cannot see the log stream or access the console and no error. It stuck in processing state.

My docker image has `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` setup like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./start_script.sh"]
CMD [ "sleep", "infinity" ]
```

I have included the container app command like

```
command = ["/bin/bash","-c","./start_script.sh"]
```

Any idea what I am missing ? I will appreciate.

Below is the docker file

```
# Use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as the base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Avoid prompts from apt
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update apt repositories and install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    curl \
    lsb-release \
    gnupg \
    python3-pip

RUN python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade \
    && pip install pyopenssl --upgrade

# Install Certbot
RUN apt-get install -y certbot

# Install certbot-dns-azure plugin via pip
RUN pip3 install certbot-dns-azure

# Install cron
RUN apt-get install -y cron

# Install Azure CLI
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a directory for scripts and the credentials file
WORKDIR /app

# Copy your scripts and credentials file into the image
COPY start_script.sh combine_and_upload.sh renew_script.sh azure_credentials.ini ./

# Set the appropriate permissions for the credentials file and make scripts executable
RUN chmod 600 azure_credentials.ini \
    && chmod +x start_script.sh combine_and_upload.sh renew_script.sh

# Set the entry point to your start script
ENTRYPOINT ["./start_script.sh"]
CMD [ "sleep", "infinity" ]
```

I run it locally as like:

```
run -d --name certbot-container -e KEYVAULT_NAME=xxx -e CERT_KEY_NAME=xxx -e DEVOPS_EMAIL=xxx -e DOMAIN=xxx -e AZURE_TENANT_DOMAIN=xxx -e CERT_NAME=xxxx registry.xxx/xxx/xx/services/certbot:v1
```

Container App Terrform Setup snippet:

```
        containers = [
          {
            image = "registry.xxx/xxx/xx/services/certbot:v1"
            command = [
              "/bin/bash",
              "-c",
              "./start_script.sh"
            ]
            env = [
              {
                name  = "KEYVAULT_NAME"
                value = azurerm_key_vault.clmDepKeyVault.name
              },
              {
                name  = "CERT_KEY_NAME"
                value = var.sslCertificateAndKeyName
              },
              {
                name  = "DEVOPS_EMAIL"
                value = var.devopsEmail
              },
              {
                name  = "DOMAIN"
                value = var.clmDomainName
              },
              {
                name  = "AZURE_TENANT_DOMAIN"
                value = var.TenantDomainName
              },
              {
                name  = "CERT_NAME"
                value = var.certbotKeyVaultCertificateName
              }
            ]
            name = "certbot"
            resources = {
              cpu    = 0.5
              memory = "1Gi"
            },
            volumeMounts = [
              {
                mountPath  = "/app"
                volumeName = "azure-credentials"
              },
              {
                mountPath  = "/etc/letsencrypt"
                subPath    = "/proxy/certbot"
                volumeName = "certbot-volume"
              }
            ]
          }
```

Comment: Can you add how do you start docker on local(command in command line)? Can you add what do you mean by `command =` is it `Command override` on `Azure`(maybe add some screenshot)?

Comment: @zori I have added more context above please

Comment: Thanks! Do your `./start_script.sh` needs `sleep infinity` as argument or it just ignoring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess as your `docker run` command to execute isn't taking any additional arguments(nothing after image name)

So you should just remove this part from your Tarraform file

```
            command = [
              "/bin/bash",
              "-c",
              "./start_script.sh"
            ]
```

And everything should work

Comment: I removed the command from terraform and nothing happens. This is why I am lost

Comment: What means `It stuck in processing state.`? it's stuck on `terraform apply` or stack on azure? did you try manually create Container App from Azure Portal without terraform? What terraform resource are you using to create this container(give full name or link)?